# PriorityQueue in Ruby

Tags: ruby, priority-queue

I continue to wonder why Ruby does not have PriorityQueue as part of core? I know I can use https://www.rubydoc.info/github/kanwei/algorithms/Containers/PriorityQueue but what if I don't have an option to install? Eg. on leetcode, I can't install gems. Is there a way to get PriorityQueue equivalent functionality using any other core features?

Comment: maybe you can implement your own priority Queue, you can get help from this blog,
https://www.brianstorti.com/implementing-a-priority-queue-in-ruby/

Comment: You can snag a copy of the source for a Ruby priority queue from the `lib` folder in [this](https://bitbucket.org/paul_j_sanchez/simplekit-ruby) bitbucket repository.  Use it at your own risk.